# Delay input placeholder re-appearance

Tags: css, placeholder

If you have an input field you can enable the placeholder property. Hence, if you write something, the text will disappear until everything is deleted, and then it re-appears again. My question is: Is it possible to delay the re-appearance of the placeholder text AFTER the true text has been deleted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an animation on the placeholder that changes its visibility from `hidden` to `visible`.

In the following example, placeholder text is shown after a delay of 1 second.

```css
::placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: showAfterDelay 0.2s ease 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes showAfterDelay {
  from { visibility: hidden; }
  to { visibility: visible; }
}

input {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="email"/>
```